# Allow/Block ports in Centos Servers

Tags: centos, iptables

How could I use linux firewall (iptables)  to allow ssh , telnet ,ftp from selected ips only ?

Comment: add somwe accept rules for your chosen ip ranges, then add after those drop rules for the ftp, ssh, and telnet port numbers.

Answer (score 0):

By default these ports are allowed. First you have to check the default policy. If it's ACCEPT, change it to DROP using

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

then you can allow specific IP for specific port. The syntax is

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport service-port -s IP-address -j ACCEPT
```

e.g.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 192.168.122.101 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score -3):

This is one format for INPUT which you can change per your requirements.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport port number -s serverip -j accept
```

Comment: it won't block other port?

Comment: In command since you are specifying the portnumber it will effect on particular number only